# programmatically login to facebook and post to page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a website, and I need it to post status updates to a Facebook Page from time to time.

Using my personal Facebook account, I created an App, and a Page. So far, I've been able to programmatically post to my Page's Wall, by adding this code to my website:

```
    <?php
session_start();
require 'src/config.php';
require 'src/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $config['App_ID'],
  'secret' => $config['App_Secret'],
  'cookie' => true
));

if(isset($_POST['status']))
{
    $page = split("-",$_POST['page']);
    $page_token = $page[0];
    $page_id= $page[1];
    // status with link
    $publish = $facebook->api('/'.$page_id.'/feed', 'post',
            array('access_token' => $page_token,
            'message'=> $_POST['status'],
            'from' => $config['App_ID'],
            'to' => $page_id,
            'caption' => 'Caption',
            'name' => 'Name',
            'link' => 'http://www.example.com/',
            'picture' => 'http://www.phpgang.com/wp-content/themes/PHPGang_v2/img/logo.png',
            'description' => $_POST['status'].' via demo.PHPGang.com'
            ));
    //Simple status without link

    //$publish = $facebook->api('/'.$page_id.'/feed', 'post',
//        array('access_token' => $page_token,'message'=>$_POST['status'] .'   via PHPGang.com Demo',
//        'from' => $config['App_ID']
//        ));

    echo 'Status updated.<br>';
    $graph_url_pages = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=".$_SESSION['token'];
    $pages = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url_pages)); // get all pages information from above url.
    $dropdown = "";
    for($i=0;$i<count($pages->data);$i++)
    {
        $dropdown .= "<option value='".$pages->data[$i]->access_token."-".$pages->data[$i]->id."'>".$pages->data[$i]->name."</option>";
    }

    echo '
    <style>
    #status
    {
        width: 357px;
        height: 28px;
        font-size: 15px;
    }
    </style>
    '.$message.'
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
    Select Page on which you want to post status: <br><select name="page" id=status>'.$dropdown.'</select><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="status" id="status" placeholder="Write a comment...." /><input type="submit" value="Post On My Page!" style="padding: 5px;" />
    <form>';

}
elseif(isset($_GET['fbTrue']))
{
    $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
        . "client_id=".$config['App_ID']."&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($config['callback_url'])
        . "&client_secret=".$config['App_Secret']."&code=" . $_GET['code'];

    $response = file_get_contents($token_url);   // get access token from url
    $params = null;
    parse_str($response, $params);

    $_SESSION['token'] = $params['access_token'];

    $graph_url_pages = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=".$_SESSION['token'];
    $pages = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url_pages)); // get all pages information from above url.
    $dropdown = "";
    for($i=0;$i<count($pages->data);$i++)
    {
        $dropdown .= "<option value='".$pages->data[$i]->access_token."-".$pages->data[$i]->id."'>".$pages->data[$i]->name."</option>";
    }

    echo '
    <style>
    #status
    {
        width: 357px;
        height: 28px;
        font-size: 15px;
    }
    </style>
    '.$message.'
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
    Select Page on which you want to post status: <br><select name="page" id=status>'.$dropdown.'</select><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="status" id="status" placeholder="Write a comment...." /><input type="submit" value="Post On My Page!" style="padding: 5px;" />
    <form>';    
}
else
{
    echo 'Connect &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id='.$config['App_ID'].'&redirect_uri='.$config['callback_url'].'&scope=publish_pages,manage_pages"><img src="./images/login-button.png" alt="Sign in with Facebook"/></a>';
}
```

So I just open my website, click "Please login", login as myself. Once I'm logged it, it will now be able to post the status update to the Facebook Page.

Obviously, the problem here is that I need to be logged in for it to be able to post. If other users will try to login with their user accounts, my website cannot post status updates to the Facebook Page because I am the only Admin for the app/Page.

My question is, is there a way for me to programmatically log myself into Facebook so I can do these status updates to my Page automatically?

Sorry, total noob here to Facebook development.

***I got a post on Stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7991180/4714813). Which had the same problem as mine. But they used "OFFLINE_ACCESS" permission to make the access token live lifelong. But Facebook removed this feature [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/roadmap/completed-changes/offline-access-removal) . so how can I do it now?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you need:

- Authorize with `publish_pages` and `manage_pages`
- Generate an [Extended User Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension)
- Use `/me/accounts` to get a list of all Pages you manage, it will include Extended Page Tokens for each Page
- Use the Extended Page Token to post, it is valid forever - or at least until you change your password or change the App Secret

More information about Access Tokens and how to get them

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: please comment a reason for a downvote. my answer is 100% correct, but i am happy to improve if there is any mistake.

Comment: I believe it does not answer the question because he stated he is having the same issue as another Stack question which involves 'OFFLINE_ACCESS' which is depreciated since 2012. I am having the same issue as Aaron so it would be awesome if you could solidify this.

Comment: what is the exact issue then? i am happy to answer additional questions related to the topic, but my answer includes a very detailed description about how to get an extended page token (which is what he needs to post without user login), and some additional links. there´s really nothing else to add. he is using a very old php sdk though, he should definitely upgrade.

Comment: in other words: you need a token that is valid forever, my answer tells you how to get one.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct. My issue deals with a Closed Group and not a page. I thought a Group consisted of Pages, but I believe that is false. My solution lies with the long-lived access token and the refreshing of that token. Sorry to waste your time, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your answer..  I searched lot and visited thousands of pages. Finally found it.